# AWS Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade Python to 2.7.10, how to deal with apt-get python-dev

Tags: ubuntu, python, upgrade, apt, pip

Ubuntu 14.04 from AWS ships with python 2.7.6.

Before doing anything else to the image, I do an upgrade to 2.7.10 by issuing

```
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential checkinstall libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
mkdir -p ~/python/2.7.10
cd ~/python/2.7.10
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.10/Python-2.7.10.tgz
tar xzf Python-2.7.10.tgz
cd Python-2.7.10
sudo ./configure
sudo make install
cd ~/
```

I use `make install` instead of `sudo make altinstall` because I want it to be the only Python 2.7 on the system, the default one.

I know there is a warning in the docs

*Warning: make install can overwrite or masquerade the python binary. make altinstall is therefore recommended instead of make install since it only installs exec_prefix/bin/pythonversion.*

Should I stick to `make altinstall`? How do I make that my default `python` then?

How do I deal with other libraries, like `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyopenssl`, which compiles some C code? In order for the C code to get compiled, I need to `sudo apt-get install python-dev` in order to get the headers. **Is this assumption wrong?** I'm a bit confused about this, as I guess that the `python-dev` in the repo is based on 2.7.6, if that makes any sense.

Additionally, since I'm running pip in a virtualenv, when issuing `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyopenssl` in there I do get a `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyOpenSSL-0.15.1.dist-info'` error, which is most likely because I'm not running sudo (but as the default user), in order for the library to get installed into the virtualenv. **What is causing this?** It doesn't happen if I do not upgrade but leave Python at 2.7.6

A last question: as soon as I upgrade python manually by compiling, am I disallowed to use the python-* packages (apt-get python-*) in the repo?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by leaving all at its default and using Docker for all non-standard versions.